# Target two separate elements on hover from css

Tags: html, css

Is possible to target two separate tables that are displayed inline on the same time? I want to have a hover effect on both table at the same time when cursor pass over `tr` `td` of first or second table.

Here is a small example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/17/

(now is working separately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort of emulate this behaviour, in that hovering over the first `div` will trigger a response in the `table` contained  in the sibling `div`:

```
div:hover,
div:hover + div table td {
    background-color: #f90;
    border-color: #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ksb2W/18/).

But you can't hover over the first `table` to trigger a response in the second, as that would require travelling to the `table`'s parent `div` then to the sibling and then to the child-table.

Similarly, without JavaScript, you can't trigger a a response in a specific row, or cell, based on the currently-hovered element in the first table. Nor, on hovering the second `table` (or `div`) can you trigger a response in the first.

Comment: hmmm Thank you anyway Thomas.

Comment: You're welcome, sorry I couldn't give you the answer that you wanted. =/